# Haskell Bubble Sort on a three part Tuple

Tags: haskell, bubble-sort

I am trying to implement bubble sort to sort my list by priority. For example, the list is of the following format with the 3rd element being priority:

```
  [("Ted", 100, 3), ("Boris", 100, 1), ("Sam", 100, 2)]
```

I have tried the standard bubble sort method below, however this did not work. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
bubbleSort :: (Ord t) => [t] -> [t]
bubbleSort a = loop (length a) bubble a

bubble :: (Ord t) => [t] -> [t] 
bubble (a:b:c) | a < b = a : bubble (b:c)
           | otherwise = b : bubble (a:c)
bubble (a:[]) = [a] 
bubble [] = []

loop :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> (t -> t) -> t -> t
loop num f x | num > 0 =  loop (num-1) f x'
         | otherwise = x
         where x' = f x
```

Comment: Your function sorts on the whole tuple, so you need to modify something if you want it to sort on the third element of the tuple.  BTW, never use bubble sort.

Comment: @augustss what can i use over bubble sort? insertion sort?. Why shouldn't i use bubble sort?

Comment: It's just that bubble sort is horribly inefficient.

Comment: @user2214957, because it's very slow.  BTW, if this is not just an experiment to see if you can implement a sorting algorithm, you might want to look at [`Data.List.sortBy`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v:sortBy)

Comment: @luqui i am just using it as a learning curve to be honest. Its not meant to be efficient at this stage.

Comment: @user2214957 If you want a simple sorting algorithm I suggest insertion sort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As hinted by luqui, it is normal to implement not the `Ord` constrained version of a sorting algorithm directly, but a more general one that uses a custom comparison:

```
bubbleSortBy :: (t->t->Ordering) -> [t] -> [t]
bubbleSortBy cmp a = loop (length a) bubble a
 where
       bubble :: (Ord t) => [t] -> [t] 
       bubble (a:b:c) = case cmp a b of
                          LT -> a : bubble (b:c)
                          _  -> b : bubble (a:c)
       bubble l = l

loop :: Integral a    -- (Num, Ord) is a bit /too/ general here, though it works.
   => a -> (t -> t) -> t -> t
loop num f x | num > 0    = loop (num-1) f x'
             | otherwise  = x
         where x' = f x
```

the `Ord` version follows trivially from this:

```
bubbleSort :: (Ord t) -> [t] -> [t]
bubbleSort = bubbleSortBy compare
```

but often is more practical to use general version directly, like in your case

```
import Data.Function(on)

sorted_priority3rd = bubbleSortBy ( compare `on` \(a,b,c) -> (c,a,b) )
```

What this does is, it changes the order of arguments before each comparison. Obviously, this makes the bubble sort even slower; normally you'd rather do

```
import Data.List (sortBy)   -- this is a proper ( log ) sorting algorithm

sorted_by3rd = sortBy ( compare `on` \(a,b,c) -> c )
```

and care about the finer order later.

Comment: Thanks for this. if the list elements were switched around so that the priority was in the first position, my basic code above in the question should work right?. The sort will operate on the first item it finds?.

Comment: It will operate on whatever the `Ord` instance defines. In the case of 3-tuples this happens to be: priority on first element, then second, then third, only then `EQ`.